# TERM environment variable not set with Docker on Google Compute Engine

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine

I am using Docker on Google Compute Engine (with a container-vm image). When I try to run:

```
# docker exec mycontainer top
```

I get:

```
TERM environment variable not set.
```

However, the term variable seems correctly setup:

```
# docker exec mycontainer echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 3):

You're evaluating the local `TERM` variable, not the one in the container. For example:

```
 X=bla && docker run debian echo $X
 bla
```

You can use single quotes:

```
X=bla && docker run debian sh -c 'echo $X'
```

Of course, `env` will also show you what is set:

```
$ docker run debian env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=3737f39f89b3
HOME=/root
```

I believe the `TERM` variable is only set automatically if the container is launched with the `-t` flag, but you can set it manually:

```
$ docker run -t debian env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=0bf3eef92d94
TERM=xterm
HOME=/root
```

Comment: You are right. When running with -t the $TERM env variable is set.